# Why same images are showing different looking on different roku devices?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I have created more then one Grid by Markup Grid node to display thumbnail,
 I have tested it in different roku devices(Roku-3, Roku-4 and Rock-stick).
 The thumbnails are looking good in Roku-4 but Roku-3 and Rock-stick look pixelated or stretch.
 Thumbnail should be display same in all devices Please provide suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: please include the exact model numbers of each device (there have been >1 "stick" and "roku 2"), as well as what's the display resolution chosen from the player's Settings menu?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I setup both ("stick" and "roku 3") devices resolution 1080pHD TV and  model no  receptively "3600X - Roku Stick" and "4200X - Roku 3"

Comment: ... and the Roku4 display resolution is?

Comment: The Roku4 display resolution is 1080pHD TV. If change the roku4 display resolution is 720pHD TV, then faced the same problem like "stick" and "roku 3".

Answer (score 1):

I think Roku-4 can natively render the RSG UI in FHD, where the "lesser" models render natively in HD. That would mean on model# <4400 if app is designed for 1080, the images getting first down-scaled to 720 to compose the buffer - and then up-scaled from that to 1080 - with the potentially undesired result of pixelation

See if this is mentioned somewhere on https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Specifying+Display+Resolution